# execute commands as parameters in a login shell

Tags: bash

We started using a new integration and production pipeline called GO. To execute a bash script there, the convenient way is to use the bash command instead of executing the script directly. For that the bash is called in a login shell, so the command I'm trying to execute the following:

```
bash -l run_tests `cat myserver.url`:8080
bash -l run_tests $(cat myserver.url):8080
```

But the whole `cat myserver.url` is passed as a string instead of being executed. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a little test script

```
$ cat run_tests 
echo "$@"
echo $0 Starting tests with $1
echo tests done
```

and ran following, (note quotes around -c "string")

```
$ bash -l -c "./run_tests $(cat furl):8080"
http://abc.com/:8080
./run_tests Starting tests with http://abc.com/:8080
tests done
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works like charm, only by convention you have to remove the -c since this param is assosiated with passing linux commands not files, I corrected my question. Many thanks!!!!